# Centering a group of Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have some `PictureBox`s (of the same width and height) which I'd like to put in some sort of container so I can vertically and horizontally align them to the center, even if I resize the window.
Which container should I use and how?
**Edit:**
[image]

So, if I resize and shrink the width of the window one card from the 1st row should move to the 2nd (because it has no space for itself), or if I resize and expand the width of the window so that it'll have space for another card, one card from the 2nd row should go back to the 1st.
Also, I want the `Panel` that contains the cards to be centered.

Comment: use Panel as container and docking for alignments

Comment: @Pankaj But I want the width and height of the panel to be automatic according to the content inside.

Comment: if you anchor the panel, it will automatically resize when you change the dimensions of the form

Comment: @Pankaj You're right, but I was already able to do that. Now I want the content inside of the panel (the pictures) to be centered inside the panel itself.

Comment: @AnDrOiD, can you please post a screenshot of layout you are trying to make?

Comment: And what's the expected layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlowLayoutPanel` can wrap controls if doesn't have place for them in current line

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Anchor = 
      AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Panel {BackColor = Color.Green, Width = 75, Height = 100, Margin = new Padding(4)});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a panel Set the anchoring to Top, Left, Bottom and Right (so that it resizes to all direction), add a picture box to it and Set the Dock of picture box to Fill. Now your picturebox will be centered inside the panel when you change the dimnensions